# Displaying data with their average rating

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join

I'm trying to display data from database with their average rating. This is my code :-

```
$packages = DB::table('packages')
                ->join('agents', 'packages.agent_id', '=', 'agents.id')
                ->join('comments', 'packages.package_id', '=', 'comments.package_id')
                ->orderBy('packages.created_at', 'desc')
                ->select(DB::raw('avg(comments.rating) as rating'), 'agents.*', 'packages.*')
                ->groupBy('comments.package_id')
                ->paginate(8);
```

and this is my error

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'traventure.agents.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select avg(comments.rating) as rating, `agents`.*, `packages`.* from `packages` inner join `agents` on `packages`.`agent_id` = `agents`.`id` inner join `comments` on `packages`.`package_id` = `comments`.`package_id` group by `comments`.`package_id` order by `packages`.`created_at` desc limit 8 offset 0)

I hope somebody helps me with my problem. Thanks.

Comment: This is not really related to Laravel but more to SQL. You could either set your MySQL mode to non strict (https://mattstauffer.com/blog/strict-mode-and-other-mysql-customizations-in-laravel-5-2/) Or you can leave out the agents.*, packages.* since they are not aggregates and are not in the group by clause.

Comment: i need to also get data from the packages and agents. If im going to leave that out, it will give me error

Comment: Either add a subquery or disable strict mode as shown in the link I provided.